# Java Beginner - Counting number of words in sentence

Tags: java, methods

I am suppose to use methods in order to count number of words in the a sentence. I wrote this code and I am not quite sure why it doesn't work. No matter what I write, I only receive a count of 1 word. If you could tell me how to fix what I wrote rather than give me a completely different idea that would be great:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P5_7 
{
    public static int countWords(String str)
    {
        int count = 1;
        for (int i=0;i<=str.length()-1;i++)
        {
            if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' && str.charAt(i+1)!=' ')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
        String sentence = in.next();
        System.out.print("Your sentence has " + countWords(sentence) + " words.");
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it not working?  Is there an exception, or just an incorrect output?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Can you provide examples of input and output?

Comment: You're not accounting for corner cases such as: the string is blank; there are blanks at the end; the string is NULL.  Also word separators are 'whitespace' which includes tabs, line endings, etc.  Also your algorithm assumes that there is at least one word in the string.

Comment: no matter what i get only 1 word at the end. and im just a beginner so all these exception are relatively irrelevant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read entire line. Instead of `in.next();` use `in.nextLine()`.

Comment: god bless! (not really religious but still...)

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to solve this problem:

```
return str.split(" ").length;
```

Or to be more careful, this is how you'd take into account more than one whitespace:

```
return str.split("\\s+").length;
```

Comment: `split("\\W+")` even - but op specified *rather than give me a completely different idea*...

Comment: still - only 1 word. I think the method is fine, maybe something wrong with the Scanner input?

Comment: @user2266957 For the above to work, the whole text must be read into a single string before calling the method

Answer (score 4):

Try This Simple Code with split() and argument as spaces

```
int length=str.split(" ").length;
```

It will return number of words in your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Should you not have `int count = 0;` instead of `int count = 1;`, in case of blank sentences. If you're getting Java errors please could you add them to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`i<=str.length()-1` should probably be `i<str.length()-1` or you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException at `str.charAt(i+1)` (the available values are `str.charAt(0)` to `str.charAt(str.length()-1)`).

Answer (score 0):

Please check for boundary conditions at `str.charAt(i+1)`. It can result in a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when the string is terminated by a space.

1. Account for cases where the string starts with a ' '
2. The String could be blank.
3. The definition of a 'word' could differ. For example - '1 2'. Are 1,2 words ?

I know you do not want an alternate method but string.split(" ").length() is an easier way to start.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you enter a sentence like:

```
"Hello World"
```

your code `String sentence = in.next();` will only get the first word in the sentence i.e., `Hello`.
So, you need to use `in.nextLine()` in place of `in.next()` to get the whole sentence i.e., `Hello World`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have done it :

It works fine too

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class countwords {

        public static void main(String args[]){
            Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter your sentence:[Try to ignore space at end]");
            String s=in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Size of the string is "+s.length());
            int res=count(s);
            System.out.println("No of words in the given String --->>"+"  "+s+" "+"is"+" :"+res);
        }


        private static int count(String s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int count=0;
            if(s.charAt(0)!=' '){
                count++;
            }
            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
                if((s.charAt(i)==' ')){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }


}
```

OUTPUT: 
this is my world bonaza

Size of the string is 23

No of words in the given String --->>  this is my world bonazais :5

There are some bugs try to correct them and repost

A more simple way that i found was :

Just use this :

```
    // Read a string
String st=s.nextLine();

// Split string with space
String words[]=st.trim().split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This program works fine,
```

step1:input the string

step2:split the string into single word store in a arrays

step3 :return the length of the arrays

```
public class P5_7 
{
public static int countWords(String str)
{
   String words[]=str.split(" ");
   int count=words.length;
    return count;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
    String sentence =in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Your sentence has " + countWords(sentence) + " words.");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Tested method - handles all inputs

```
public static void countwords() {
    String s = "  t    ";
    int count = 0;
    int length = s.length()-1;
    char prev = ' ';

    for(int i=length; i>=0; i--) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(c != prev && prev == ' ') {
            count++;
        }
        prev = c;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple logic is count the spaces only if there aren't any white spaces before.
Try this:

```
public class WordCount 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int word=1;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String str=s.nextLine();
        for(int i=1;i<str.length();i++)
            {
                if(str.charAt(i)==' ' && str.charAt(i-1)!=' ')
                word++;
            }
       System.out.println("Total Number of words= "+word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.Map;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordrCount {

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your String: ");
    final Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String s1 = sc.nextLine();
    final String[] c1 = s1.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < c1.length; i++) {
        if (!hm.containsKey(c1[i])) {
            hm.put(c1[i], (Integer)1);
        }// if
        else {
            hm.put(c1[i], hm.get(c1[i]) +(Integer) 1);

        }// else
    }// for

    System.out.println("The Total No Of Words: " + hm);

}// main
```

}// WordCount

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [BreakIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html). This is the best way to cover not standard languages like Japanese where there aren't spaces that separates words.

Example of word counting [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/breakiterator.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more method just using `split`, `trim`, `equals` methods to improve code and performance.

> This code will work with space as well.

```
public int countWords(String string){
    String strArr [] = string.split("\\s");
    int count = 0;
    for (String str: strArr) {
        if(!str.trim().equals("")){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this method to calculate the number of words in a String:-

```
    private int calculateWords(String s){

    int count=0;

    if(s.charAt(0)!=' ' || s.charAt(0)!=','){

        count++;

    }

    for(int i=1;i<s.length();i++){
            if((s.trim().charAt(i)==' ' && s.charAt(i+1)!=' ')  || (s.trim().charAt(i)==',' && s.charAt(i+1)!=',')){

                count++;
            }

    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Words {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str="Hello World this is new";
    str=str.trim();
    int n=str.length();
    char a[]=new char[n];
    str.getChars(1,n,a,0);
    for (int i=0;i<str.length() ; i++){
        if(a[i]==' ') count++;
    }
    System.out.println("No. of words = "+(count+1));
}
```

}

Comment: The above is very easy one to understand.

Answer (score -1):

```
package test;
public class CommonWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String words = "1 2 3 44 55                            966 5                                   88              ";
        int count = 0;
        String[] data = words.split(" ");
        for (String string : data) {
            if (!string.equals("")) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```