# Dropdown duplicate value automation using Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver, dropdown

How to check the duplication of values in a checkbox using Selenium Webdriver

Comment: Add them to a `Set` and verify that the size of the set is the same as the size of the list.

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: I'm using Java & webdriver

Comment: Your code trials please.

Answer (score 1):

something like the below one will work if both the options have same value

```
public boolean isSelectOptionsRepeating(WebElement dropdown)
{
    Select s = new Select(dropdown);
    List<WebElement> list = s.getOptions();
    Set<String> listNames = new Hashset<String>(list.size());
    for (WebElement w : list) {
        listNames.add(w.getText().trim());
    }

    if(list.size()== listNames.size())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I want to check the duplication on values in a single dropdown. Thanks

Comment: So adapt this snippet of code to your situation. You haven't provided any code, so we can't be expected to be any more precise than that.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can store the values of drop down in String array and
2. traverse string array and use Hashmap for storing the values from the dropdown and if duplicate occurs increement the count by one
3. voila......you would know the the Values with its count, if count > 1. Duplicate
4. for reference : [Java Beginner - Counting number of words in sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930946/java-beginner-counting-number-of-words-in-sentence?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)