# Searching array return count found

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, search, actionevent

I have an button that I am trying to configure. What I need it to do look at a textArea and compare it to a list of phrases and return a number of matches found from list that were in the text area.  Any help appreciated. THanks

```
 verifyJButton = new JButton("Verify"); //Create verify button
 add(verifyJButton); //add button to a box
 verifyJButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()//set action for button
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event2)
                {
                    //user pressed verify button
                    for (String keywords = 0; keywords < 

                    }                        
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(label, this, "The spam score for this message is", WIDTH);
                }
```

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: I added code to my post. say i have a list containing "here" ,"there"," for", "why". in the interface I paste a random paragraph of text and whenI click the verify button it look at the list and give me a number for how many times is sees any of the words in the list

Answer (score 0):

[Java Beginner - Counting number of words in sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930946/java-beginner-counting-number-of-words-in-sentence)

Above answer might help you on how you can get count for a specific word in a textArea